# AWS Lambda Node.js 12.x force exit

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, setinterval

I am using CloudWatch events to trigger a Lambda. The Lambda needs to perform a task within a couple seconds of the start of the 59th minute in a hour. For the sake of simplicity lets say it is to save an entry in DynamoDb.

Cloutwatch events can't guarantee an exact time of execution, so I set it up to trigger at 58 minutes past the hour, the Lamaba then executes a piece of code like below, where I call a function every second. I set the Lambda to timeout after 90 seconds.

```
exports.handler = (event) => {
    let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    //snip..
    setInterval(function() {
      var date = (new Date()).toISOString();
      var minutesAndSecondsOfHour = parseInt(date.slice(14,16) + date.slice(17,19);
      if(minutesAndSecondsOfHour >= 5900) {
        ddb.put(...);
        // somehow exit
      }
    
    }, 1000);
//snip
```

I don't know how to exit the lambda after performing my task with a success code. I have tried `process.exit(0)', but if I use the save to DynamoDb doesn't complete.

If I remove the `process.exit(0)` and let the Lambda timeout, the save to DynamoDb works but the Lambda exits with a timeout error.

Comment: Stop the interval.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: Your interval keeps running (unnecessarily) after the time is hit and the entry is saved. So, stop it after it hits the time.

Comment: I was unaware of the the clearInterval(..) method. That worked. Thanks. Do you want to add an answer so I can accept it.